# integer literals as byte variables/parameters: when exactly does the compiler complain?

Tags: java, java-7, javac

In the following code:

```
public class FooMain {


    private static void foo(byte b) {}

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        byte b1 = 0;                // javac doesn't complain
        byte b2 = 127+30000-30000;  // javac apparently does arithmetic and doesn't complain
        foo(0); // javac complains here and requires a cast to (byte). Why?
    }
}
```

why does the `javac` compiler complain on the call to `foo` while it is apparently able to deduce that the literals or even literal arithmetic expressions supplied are safe to be assigned to `byte` variables? I am using Oracle javac 1.7.0_60.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java uses something called Assignment conversion in the first two places where it is legal to implicitly narrow down datatypes.

But in the third case, Java does something called Method Invocation Conversion - which explicitly requires the programmer to specify a narrowing conversion.

[This link might help.](http://www.javaranch.com/journal/200508/ScjpTipLine-conversions2.html)

Answer (score 1):

The compiler will not convert an int to a byte without an explicit cast in other cases, but in case of assignment if the value is a statically-known constant, then the compiler will perform the conversion automatically.

This explains all your 3 cases.

- Assignment with statically known constant

  ```
  byte b1 = 0;
  ```
- Assignment with statically known constant. The computation is done at compile time.

  ```
  byte b2 = 127+30000-30000;
  ```
- Not an assignment

  ```
  foo(0);
  ```